# Heating element as resistor for motor fan assembly in heat gun

Tags: tools, troubleshooting

Repairing the heat gun is not an option at this point, but out of curiosity I want to dig deeper into the problem:

There are four wires associated with the heating element assembly, two of which connect with the motor and ventilation fan assembly.

One heat gun pushes air without noise. In this case, the heat gun does not produce substantial heat, but the motor runs at a normal speed and there is no noticeable vibration.

The other heat gun produces heat, but the motor is going so fast my friend labelled it as "broken." The instrument vibrates and the noise is obnoxious. At first I believed there was something wrong with the fan assembly, such as an imbalanced or missing fan blade, but switching the fan parts produces the same result. I believe the faster operation is due to an electrical difference.

Has anyone encountered this before? Maybe the heating element doubles as a resistor for the fan / motor assembly? Lacking the equipment to test for this has left me guessing.

Answer (score 3):

These hair dryer type blowers use DC motors with AC , a power diode , switch and a hot resistor using Nichrome wire.

When the coils short circuit from heat warp, they dump more current in the motor and less power into the coil.   Fix the coil short and the RPM and heat will return to normal.

Comment: I lack the points necessary to upvote, but thank you for the information about what kind of wire is used. I will research the procedures of how to rejoin the coils (assuming solder is not an option since it runs at 1050ish degrees Fahrenheit) (my solder melts pretty easily around 700). I may have to ask a friend to weld it. This is amusingly complicated, but all of the trouble I am going through to fix this will give me a better understanding to pursue my ambitions.

I noticed when I opened the unit, the cathode (black) wire on the motor was no longer connected. Did heat melt the connection?

Comment: I simply crimp by twisting, which only lasts as long until it oxides, mica insulation may not have held in place the warped Nickel-Chromium or Nichrome resistance wires which shorted. I assume black wire makes motor run, so no.

Comment: Since wire is wrinkled or coiled, it may have stretched to touch another path of the coil return. So my understanding is it is a shortened coil, not an open connection.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the schematic of a [typical Revlon hair dryer](http://shaddack.twibright.com/projects/repair_hairdryer/) (of which your heat gun is probably functionally similar-- perhaps a subset with two speeds):

[image]

The schematic form looks correct, but he says the actual ratio of the divider feeding the motor is about 1:4. Since the motor is 18V nominal, if we assume the resistor marked 89\$\Omega\$ is actually 121\$\Omega\$ and the resistor marked 61\$\Omega\$ is actually 29\$\Omega\$, then the current through the 121\$\Omega\$ resistor is about 1.7A and the current through the 29\$\Omega\$ resistors is about 0.6A, leaving about 1.1A for the motor.

[image]

If the heater coil fails open in the 29\$\Omega\$ segment (marked 61\$\Omega\$ in the schematic) then the motor voltage will increase to more than 50% above nominal in the switch positions medium and high. In the low switch position, due to the series diode, the motor voltage will be somewhat below nominal, so it would not make too much of a racket, but it would be running significantly faster than normal **for that switch position**.

So, I suggest there is a failure in the heater winding, either at the termination or in the smaller of the two parts of the tapped winding.

Comment: I need to study a bit before I am able to leverage this information. The concepts make sense, but I am too new to this to make the information actionable. Thank you for being so thorough. Unfortunately I can not award points yet.